# Почему keyof IItem возвращает string | number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, angular, generics

Довольно специфичное поведение, которое я никак не могу побороть...

```
interface IItem {
    [key: string]: string;
}

type t = keyof IItem; // string | number
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures это же прямым тестом в документации описано. `keyof T` will be `string | number` (and not just `string` ...

Comment: Вообще такой интерфейс проще записать как `type IItem = Record<string, string>;`